# ¿Como guardar en SharedPreferences segun posicion de RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, sharedpreferences

Estoy guardando una lista con múltiples datos en un `SharedPreferences`, lo paso con `gson.toJson` para convertirlo en un `String` y así guardarlo sin problema alguno. Lo obtengo y lo muestro en la lista también sin problemas, el detalle esta que esto solo pasa con el primer ítem, ya que al crear el siguiente y intentar verlo me muestra el mismo valor que el ítem anterior puesto que lo estoy obteniendo con el mismo `key` del `SharedPreferences`. ¿De que forma puedo incrementar el `key` del `SharedPreferences` de manera que el mismo almacene el valor según la posición del `RecyclerView`?

Ejemplo: Si la posición es 1, lograr algo como una `key` "informacion1", si la posición esta en 5, sería "información5" y así sucesivamente. Gracias de antemano.

```
public class CreateDataPresenter implements CreateDataMVP.Presenter {

    private CreateDataMVP.View view;
    private List<DATOS> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void setView(CreateDataMVP.View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void SaveInfo() {

        String NameShowList = view.getNamelist();
        list.add(new Pos(view.getNamelist(), view.getSurnamelist(), view.getNumberfollower(), view.getIDfollower(), view.getcode()));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        PreferenceHelper.SetStringValue(view.FetchContext(), "ADD_INFO",gson.toJson(list));
        view.inputSuccess(NameShowList);
    }

    @Override
    public void ValidateFields() {

    }
}
```

Estoy usando la arquitectura `MVP`. Por eso se ve así, los métodos "get" obtengo los valores de los `EditText` en `view.FetchContext` obtengo `this` y `PreferenceHelper.SetStringValue` es un método que cree aparte para ser mas organizado. Así:

```
public static void SetStringValue(Context context, String key, String save) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref  = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref .edit();
        editor.putString(key, save);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Acá almaceno agregándolo al `Recycler`

```
DATOS object = new DATOS(value,null,null,null,null);
                int position = listAdapter.getItemCount();
                listAdapter.addItem(object, position);
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(listAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

El método `addItem`:

```
private List<DATOS> list = null; //variable global en el Adapter

public void addItem(Datos dataObj, int index) {
        list.add(dataObj);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } 

@Override
  public int getItemCount() {
  return list.size();
}
```

Comment: Hola, pon el codigo donde ya guardas en sharedPreferences para ayudarte mejor

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez listo, agregue el código de como guardo la data

Comment: pero como sabes que posicion es cual?

Comment: ya agregue lo demás, estaba editandola aun, de esa forma agrego el item.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que esto te servirá:

```
public void saveData(int position, String jsonData) {
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("jsonData_"+position, jsonData).apply();
}

public String retrieveJsonData(int position) {
    return sharedPreferences.getString("jsonData_"+position, null);
}
```

Aunque si lo que quieres es pasar información entre pantallas (actividades) yo usaría Parcelables.

Comment: Bien, el detalle es de que forma obtengo e incremento la posición el valor de la `key` según la posición del `RecyclerView`

Comment: Dentro del adapter que usa el recyclerView puedes usar el método getAdapterPosition para obtener la posición del elemento presionado, solo te faltará crear un callback en el adapter para que quien lo escuche sepa la posición elegida.